# Rails3-autocomplete-jquery multiple autocomplete method in one controller rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I'm using [rails3-autocomplete-jquery](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete). I've got the basic case working on my app. The basic case is for the code stated below of `autocomplete :vendor, :name_en`

I've dedicated my a controller to deal with autocomplete called auto_controller.rb

```
class AutoController < SplashController
  autocomplete :vino, :wine_name
  autocomplete :vendor, :name_en
end
```

Routes.rb

```
get "auto/autocomplete_wine_name" => "auto#autocomplete_wine_name", :controller => 'auto', :action => "autocomplete_wine_name", :via => :get
get "auto/autocomplete_vendor_name_en" => "auto#autocomplete_vendor_name_en", :controller => 'auto', :action => "autocomplete_vendor_name_en", :via => :get
```

I'm getting an unknown action when I access `/auto/autocomplete_wine_name`, but when I access `/auto/autocomplete_vendor_name_en` it works okay. The error I get is as follows:

```
Unknown action

The action 'autocomplete_wine_name' could not be found for AutoController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the class name (vino) in your route, shouldn't your routes file be:

```
get "auto/autocomplete_vino_wine_name" => "auto#autocomplete_vino_wine_name", :controller => 'auto', :action => "autocomplete_vino_wine_name", :via => :get
```

Comment: That it's it. Thanks for the prompt response.